# Цвет текста в консоли

Tags: c#, color, консоль

Хочу выделить максимальный элемент в массиве красным цветом,но выделяется элемент стоящий за максимальным. Если можно укажите на ошибку и способ её исправления. Вот код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(A[i, j] + " ");
        if (A[i, j] == max)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        }
        else Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сначала выводите результат, а потом проверяете на максимум и меняете цвет.

```
{
    if (A[i, j] == max)
    {
         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    }
    else Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write(A[i, j] + " ");
}
```

Вот так будет правильней.

Comment: Точно!)  Savro,Спасибо вам огромное :)